# cannot compile anything with gcc on cygwin32; missing cygisl-10.dll

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have a problem wit compilation with gcc on 32-bit cygwin. 
The message is:

```
C:/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygisl-10.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And that is true. I have cygisl-13.dll instead of cygisl-10.dll. I'm not sure whether this is just more recent version of the same library or something different.

On the other hand I do have cygisl-10.dll but not cygisl-13.dll in cygwin64 and I'm able to compile programs.

Is it configuration issue or broken package database?

Comment: Hi again. I updated to 5.2.0, it seems buggy with string. So I downgrade it back to 4.9.3 by using the option "Install from Local Directory". Compilation works. wtf. The cygisl-10.dll is from C:\cygwin64\bin. 

Or try to rename cygisl-13.dll to cygisl-10.dll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file is part of the *libisl10* package:

```
$ apt-cyg listfiles libisl10 | grep cygisl-10.dll
usr/bin/cygisl-10.dll
```

Comment: Right! It were dependencies untracked by cygwin. After installing libisl10 and libcloog-isl4 compilation work like a harm. Thanks