# Cygwin won't compile any c++ files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cygwin

When I try to compile my Fibonacci.cpp file I get this from the compiler:

```
$ g++ Fibonacci.cpp
C:/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygcloog-isl-4.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've downloaded the `gcc-g++: GNU Compiler Collection (C++)` library and it's not working. Am I missing another library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the  libcloog-isl4 package when you run the setup.exe. You are missing that file in your C:/cygwin64/bin directory. I had the same problem and I was also missing  cygisl-10.dll and I had to install libisl10 package.

See  this [cannot compile anything with gcc on cygwin32; missing cygisl-10.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897685/cannot-compile-anything-with-gcc-on-cygwin32-missing-cygisl-10-dll).

Unfortunately I'm getting a different error now that I solved that, so I'm not guaranteeing a fix.

Comment: dont answer using links they can go bad at some point and then your answer will be invalid

Comment: when the same error occurs using MSYS2, simply `pacman -S isl`. still, explaining what `isl` or `cloog` are, why they're needed, and why they're not installed as standard, etc... would've been useful. i still don't know. edit: "Necessary to build GCC with the Graphite loop optimizations" - https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html / "isl [Integer Set Library] is a library for manipulating sets and relations of integer points bounded by linear constraints." - http://isl.gforge.inria.fr/ / and there we have it.